# How to define current product thumbnail in woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I am currently working on a shop page which works with Wordpress + Woocommerce Plugin. I edited the woocommerce Files so that I have custom products, menus and so on.

I managed to get current images from my products, but now I want them to appear on click (the little image Icon, on the Screenshot)

[image: Screenshot Shop Site]

But instead of showing the current product image it shows the first image of each category

[image: Screenshot showing wrong product].

Here is my current code that loads the wrong product thumbnail:

```
 <div class="modal-content">
   <a itemprop="image" href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() ); ?>" class="zoom" rel="thumbnails" title="<?php echo get_the_title( get_post_thumbnail_id() ); ?>">
   <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(  $post->ID, apply_filters( 'single_product_large_thumbnail_size', 'shop_single' ) ) ?>
</a></div>
```

It is located in woocommerce/content-product.php.

Thank you in advance

Nico

Comment: are you on product page??

Comment: What do you mean, the products are loaded in the product categorie page. You can take a look if you want [ShopPage](https://shop.ems-online.ch/produkt-kategorie/bueromaterial/)

Comment: no such popup functionality there

Comment: I created a modal which pop ups if you click on the red icon. Its from my framework I used (materializecss)

Comment: <script>
    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

    // Get the button that opens the modal
    var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    // When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
    btn.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "block";
    }

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }

Comment: can you share product category page content??

Comment: That worked, take a look in the following screenshots:http://prnt.sc/dqy08c and http://prnt.sc/dqy0hr

Comment: This is the full code: https://jsfiddle.net/m9rcbbzs/2/

Comment: ok let me check

Comment: why all load same image on click

Comment: I want to load the same image into the modal so that the user can see a better view of the picture.

Comment: product is :Kugelschreiber Caran d´Ache Classic  and popup shows EMS??

Comment: yes! the product is Kugelschreiber Caran d´Ache Classic, and when I click for the pop up, it only shows the folder - which is always this image [image seen here](http://prnt.sc/dqz1gq) It should show the image from Kugelschreiber Caran d´Ache Classic and not the one from the folder

Comment: You need to pass the product's ID to the modal. You may need to ajax load the modal's content because `$post` is determined on the server side and doesn't update dynamically depending on which product you click on. Alternatively you could find a way to store the product's large thumbnail URL in the markup (probably as a data attribute for the little icon) and then load that on click.

Comment: Ok, thank you I will try that

Comment: @helgatheviking I tried to load the image via the product ID, but that doesn't seem to work.


`<img src="<?php $thumb_id = $product->id; $thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id,'thumbnail-size', true); echo $thumb_url[0]; ?>"/>`

Comment: But as I tried to explain, that will only load *one* thumbnail on page load, the thumbnail of the current `$post` or `$product` global. And it won't dynamically change when the modal is launched. For that, you need to use Javascript/Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

So this is the solution, I had to create dynamic IDs. As I wrote it was always the same image, the reason of this was that there was only one ID and not multiple/dynamic.

This was the code I had to add to the id:

```
<div id="modal-<?php echo $product->id ?>" class="modal">
```

And here is the other one:

```
<a data-target="modal-<?php echo $product->id; ?>" class="modal-trigger"><i class="material-icons red-text right">photo</i></a>
```